# How does params work under the hood in c#

Tags: c#, .net, parameters

```
static int Sum(params int[] numbers){
    int sm = 0;
    foreach(var n in numbers){
      sm += n;
    }   
    return sm;}
```

I know the rules of the declaration and calling about the usage of params. But I wondering how it is achieved behind the scene. I guess the compiler, when it sees the params keyword, somehow redirect the inputs into a class, and the class exposed a property. And we can use the name(here is `numbers`) to access that property. These all my guess. I searched online, did not find the source code.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about arguments/parameters in general or the `params` keyword specifically?

Comment: Try compiling it and looking at the IL with ILSpy: https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy

Comment: @Joe Sewell, I am asking how the framework implement params keyword behind the scene.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, thanks, will try. I never jumped into the IL myself before.

Comment: [run-time-evaluation-of-argument-lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#run-time-evaluation-of-argument-lists)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thanks, good ref here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction) it just creates an instance of an array with the parameters you passed it.

> Within a method that uses a parameter array, the parameter array behaves exactly like a regular parameter of an array type. However, in an invocation of a method with a parameter array, it is possible to pass either a single argument of the parameter array type or any number of arguments of the element type of the parameter array. In the latter case, an array instance is automatically created and initialized with the given arguments. This example
>
> `Console.WriteLine("x={0} y={1} z={2}", x, y, z);`
>
> is equivalent to writing the following.
>
> ```
> object[] args = new object[3];
> args[0] = x;
> args[1] = y;
> args[2] = z;
> Console.WriteLine(s, args);
> ```